# How exactly work this form submission JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new in JavaScript and I have the following doubt about how exactly work this script that submit a form:

So in my html I have the following form:

```
<form id="actionButton<%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%>" action="salwf.do?serv=1" method="post">
    <button id="accept" name="ctrl" value="Accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton" onclick="sottometti(this,'<%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%>')">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button id="cancel" name="ctrl" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton" onclick="sottometti(this)">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button id="sap" name="ctrl" value="SAP" type="submit" class="sapButton" onclick="sottometti(this)">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>

    <input id="testId<%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%>" name="test" type="hidden">
</form>
```

So the submission of this form is directed towards a page **salwf.do** and each time pass a parameter named **serv** and having **1** as value (is this a GET?)

Then inside the form I have 3 **buttons** having different **id** and different **values** and the **input tag** (that I think it is what I am submitting, is it right?)

As you can see when the user click on a button is called the **sottometti(this)** script that take as parameter the reference to the object that have generated the click (in this case the clicked button)

And this is this JavaScript code:

```
function sottometti(obj,id){
    document.getElementById('testId'+id).value = obj.value;
    document.getElementById('actionButton'+id).submit()
}
```

So how exactly work this script?

I think that it do the following thing (but I am not sure about it and maybe I am missing something).

It take 2 input parameters: the clicked button reference (obj) and the id string (that represent a code of a Java object, but this is not important now).

Using:

```
document.getElementById('testId'+id)
```

it retrieve the reference of the **input tag** of the form and set the value (what I want submit) with the button value (that can be: **Accept** or **Cancel** or **Sap**)

Then by:

```
document.getElementById('actionButton'+id)
```

retrieve my form and submit it

So the value of the clicked button will be submitted to the **salwf.do** servlet as **POST**.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your reasoning is correct, but you have some issues.

1. you only pass the ID from one of the buttons - the accept one
2. For all buttons you seem to want to add Accept/Cancel/SAP to a hidden field called testAccept, testCancel or testSAP and submit a form with ID actionButtonAccept, actionButtonCancel, actionButtonSAP but do not have either the field nor the form in the Cancel/SAP situation.
3. do not submit in a click event of a submit button

I would do

```
function sottometti(obj){
  obj.form.test.value = obj.value;
  // obj.form.submit(); // all the buttons are submit buttons
}
```

Comment: what kind of issues can I have?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about one thing. Here you attach JavaScript to button[type=submit] and you execute form submit. So in fact you submit it twice.

If you want to prevent submission you should at least return false in your callback function (best is anyhow to use event.preventDefault();) like in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646215/2802756